# Force Bootstrap col below other column in 2 column layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            A   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            B     
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            C     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Filled with actual content it looks somewhat like this:
http://www.bootply.com/JZj51T1G1E#

Without changing the HTML structure, is there a way to force B to display on the left, under A? C should still stay on the right side.
I tried using pull-6, but that causes it to display over A.

Comment: Why can't you change the HTML structure?

Comment: I'm using a content management system that makes this very complicated.

Comment: *Complicated* doesn't really mean you shouldn't do it. I would strongly recommend doing this the right way rather than trying to hack the UI.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the markup, you can rearrange it using `flexbox`

Use the [**CSS3 Prefixer**](http://pleeease.io/play/) to support slightly old browsers. Output in full screen.

```css
.col-md-6:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #f00;
}
.col-md-6:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
.col-md-6:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #f0f;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; 
  }
  .col-md-6:nth-child(2) {
    order: 3;
  }
  .col-md-6:nth-child(3) {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
      <br>A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <br>B
      <br>B
      <br>B
      <br>B
      <br>B
      <br>B
      <br>B
      <br>B
      <br>B
      <br>B
      <br>B
      <br>B
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <br>C
      <br>C
      <br>C
      <br>C
      <br>C
      <br>C
      <br>C
      <br>C
      <br>C
      <br>C
      <br>C
      <br>C
      <br>C
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping more than 12 cols per row. Please wrap 12 or less cols per row like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            A   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            B     
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            C     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code structure is the correct way of adding columns in bootstrap and it also moves B to the left below A as you wanted.

Comment: Question states "Without changing the HTML structure".

Comment: @1nterference The html structure is broken. Fixing that will fix his issue too. If it's not broken, I won't have mentioned it in the first place :)

Comment: @1nterference Check this: https://github.com/twbs/bootlint You will know what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear:left` to the CSS of your second div. This, however, won't change the fact that C is also below A.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            A   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 second-col">
            B     
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            C     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.second-col{
    clear:left;
  }
```

Comment: C needs to be on the right side, question didn't make that clear. Edited.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this without eventually altering the structure, or mutilating Bootstrap to the point that it would be 'inefficient' to use it in the first place. It seems like the real problem is with the content management system that you are using that prevents you from altering the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 5 you can set the vertical order using [Order](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#order).

For example, this column will place on top in a small/mobile layout, but align on the right after other columns when the screen-size grows:

`<div class="col-md-8 order-first order-sm-last">`